# Client control in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, transactions

In my flex app, where should i store session data?

My business code is exposed in a SOA way and the communication between client code and the backend takes place at very precise moments yet i have to keep variables in the flex client so the user may resume in case of failure. I'd like this flow of events to be feasible.

1. user1 logins and makes some actions
2. failure due to the unexpected events (logout not in due time, exception in client code, closed browser, communications breakdown, etc)
3. user2 logins, makes some actions and commits successfully
4. user1 logins again and resumes where he left in point 2 since the client app loaded the sharedObject for user1

Is this feasible with shraredObjects?, what's common practice to deal with this?, also i cannot impose the user to tweak her/his browser to accept sharedObjects.

Thanks in advance

P.S: I don't want to use fine-grained communication between client and business code to control the current state of the client, business code is SOA style, and also the backing-bean used in BlazeDS is heavily loaded.

Comment: I would advise you to take a look at any MVC framework.
Robotlegs would be preferrable http://www.robotlegs.org/

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to robotlegs, i really enjoyed the docs and i would give a try if i had to start from scratch, in fact i was using a layer over AS3 to integrate with spring Web Flow which leverages services with clients, and has some resemblance with most robotlegs patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as `SharedObject` is associative array, you can add current user name to key when you store data:

```
sharedObject.data[user_name + "x"] = x;
```

Or even create individual sharedObject file for each user:

```
sharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal(user_name);
sharedObject.data["x"] = x;
```

But I'd better store current state on server. This can be done on logout or on timer event to prevent heavy communication.

Comment: Yes, this is, i wish i could vote you up. Putting a timer is also a good idea.